How to do distributed processing across multiple Citrix servers?
Here is a hail-Mary kind of question in that as an employee in a firm that makes substantial use of Citrix, I have limited visibility into the operations and details of Citrix.  All I know is that I have access to a number of servers, accessible through the Citrix Workspace

menu tray app, as shown in the picture, and I can run an .NET command line executable on any one of them.  So I have been able to create a "poor man's grid" to do distributed processing simply by (manually) launching several servers, and from File Explorer in each, launching the command 10 times (with different arguments for subsets of the data).
What I would like to do, of course, at a minimum, is to be able to run an executable and specify in the arguments the server number it will be run on.  For example, assume I have Citrix servers 101, 102, and 103 (where the numbers are blurred in the snapshot.)  I would like to be able to run a batch file from any one of them
C:>
processDataFile_m_on_Server_n DataFile101 101
processDataFile_m_on_Server_n DataFile102 102
processDataFile_m_on_Server_n DataFile103 103
Is there a way to do this?  I've considered making a desktop app that does browser automation to automate the manual act of launching server 101,and launching the command, etc.  But it seems like some Citrix magic might do this in a more obvious manner.

Does this help: https://support.citrix.com/s/article/CTX482607-how-to-start-remote-app-via-mstsc-instead-of-rdp-initial-app?language=en_US ?

Writing a script to start up software remotely isn't really that new or unique a thing. What research have you done regarding this and what have you tried?
